# Does urllib.request.urlopen(url) use cache?

Tags: python, urllib

I have this long list of URL that I need to check response code of, where the links are repeated 2-3 times. I have written this script to check the response code of each URL.

```
connection =urllib.request.urlopen(url)
return connection.getcode()
```

The URL comes in XML in this format

```
 < entry key="something" > url</entry>
 < entry key="somethingelse" > url</entry>
```

and I have to associate the response code with the attribute Key so I don't want to use a SET.

Now I definitely don't want to make more than 1 request for the same URL so I was searching whether urlopen uses cache or not but didn't find a conclusive answer. If not what other technique can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Is each key unique to each URL? So each key maps to one and only one URL and each URL maps to one and only one key?

Comment: No multiple keys can map to the same URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the urls in a dictionary (`urls = {}`) as you make a request and check if you have already made a req to that url later:

```
if key not in urls:
  connection = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  urls[key] = url
  return connection.getcode()
```

BTW if you make requests to the same urls repeatedly (multiple runs of the script), and need a persistent cache, i recommend using [requests](http://python-requests.org/) with [requests-cache](https://github.com/reclosedev/requests-cache)

Comment: For multiple runs of the scripts I actually want each unique URL to be hit atleast once. But for a single run i dont want to hit the same URL more than once. I will explore the dictionary option.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create a python `set()` of the URLs? That way each url is included only once.

Comment: No that might be a problem the link comes in XML tags with different attributes for the tag like this . And i need to associate them with the key.

< entry key="something" > url</entry>
< entry key="somethingelse" > url</entry>

Answer (score 1):

How are you associating the URL with the key? A dictionary?

You can use a dictionary to map the URL to it's response and any other information you need to keep track of. If the URL is already in the dictionary then you know the response. So you have one dictionary:

```
url_cache = {
    "url1" : ("response", [key1,key2])
    }
```

If you need to organize things differently it shouldn't be too hard with another dictionary.